# Is @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) generate a Unique Value

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I have the annotation below:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long userID;
```

Will it generate a unique value? Environment is Google App Engine which doesn't support Unique constraint annotation.

Any documentations please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The source code tells you the answer, particularly the comments
http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/valuegenerator/SequenceGenerator.java